What is the need of the data in this ques if for occurence to be exactly $10$, probability will be $F(10) - F(9)$?
An urn contains $25$ paisa and $50$ paisa coins. $200$ times coins are chosen from the urn with
replacement and found that the number of $50$ paisa coins among those $200$ coins was only $8$.
With proper explanation, find the probability that the number of $50$ paisa coins will be $10$ during the experiment. Given that $F(9) = 0.7166$ and $F(10) = 0.8159$, where $F(.)$ denotes the cdf of Poisson distribution.
Is my thinking that $F(10) - F(9)$ will give me the probability that the number of $50$ paisa coins will be $10$ during the experiment wrong??

The Poisson distribution has a parameter. What is the value of that parameter for the $F$ you have given?

this is only given in the ques.

I do not understand the question, as the distribution would be binomial rather than Poisson, and conditioned on $8$ fifties having been drawn, the probability of $10$ fifties having been drawn is $0$, while the future predictive distribution depends on the particular prior you might use.  But if $X$ is distributed on the non-negative integers saying $\mathbb P(X=n) = \mathbb P(X\le n)- \mathbb P(X\le n-1)=F(n)-F(n-1)$ is correct.  Using R, ppois(10,8) gives 0.8158858 while ppois(9,8) gives 0.7166243, and their difference is dpois(10,8) i.e. 0.0992615.

Let $A$ be the number of $25's$ and $B$ the number of $50's$.
Clearly, $B$ must be very small compared to $A$.  So small that we can regard the selection of a $50$ to be a Poisson event, rather than just use the binomial.
If we  regard the experiment as a Poisson trial with expected value $8$ we do indeed get the indicated values. And, as you say, the implied probability of getting exactly $10$ would be $F(10)-F(9)=.09926$.
Note, if we did the same thing via the binonial distribution, we'd start by letting $A$ be the number of $25's$ and $B$ the number of $50's$ from which we'd note that the expected number is $\frac B{A+B}\times 200$ From which we conclude that $$\frac B{A+B}\sim \frac 8{200}\implies B\sim \frac A{24}$$
This tells us that the probability of getting a $50$ in a single draw is about $\frac 1{25}$ so we can use that in the binomial distribution to see that the probability of drawing exactly $10$ of $.10078$  so quite close.  To be sure, we are only approximating the single draw probability so there is no "exact" answer available.
